# include and function not working

Tags: php, pdo, firephp

Hi I still cannot figure out why these codes are not working and they have not produced out any error though I have tested the [small example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104998/how-can-call-function-of-one-php-file-from-another-php-file-and-pass-parameter-t) and it worked.

Here are these codes:
securedlogin.php

```
<?php
include_once '/../toggleFirePHP.php'; //ok
// Start here...................................................................
function connect($database)
{
$firephp->group("In securedlogin.php, debugging begins");
$firephp->info("Info: Building parameters before login and use database");

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'root';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = '';

/*** mysql database ***/

$firephp->log("Log: hostname=".$hostname.", username=".$username.", password=".$password.", database=".$database);

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    echo 'Connected to '.$database.' database'."<br/>";
    $firephp->warn("Warn: Login and connected to $database database is successful!");
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    $shorterr = $e->getMessage();
    $alertmsg = $shorterr;
    include 'alertmessage.php'; 
    echo $shorterr."<br/>";
    $firephp->error("Error: Login and connected to database is NOT successful! See below:");
    $firephp->error("Error: $shorterr");
    }

$firephp->groupEnd();
}
?>
```

toggleFirePHP.php

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['Document_ROOT'].'/firephp_include.php');
$firephp->setEnabled(TRUE);
?>
```

main.php

```
<?php
include_once '/toggleFirePHP.php'; //ok

// Start here...................................................................
include_once 'secured/securedlogin.php';

$firephp->group("In main.php, debugging begins");
$database = 'testdata1970_05';
$firephp->log("Log: Include securedlogin.php once and use $database");
connect($database);

$firephp->groupEnd();
?>
```

So what went wrong with these codes?
Your help would be fully appreciated.
Clement

Comment: Have you tried adding this at the beginning of both your phps? - "global $firephp;"

Comment: How it is "not working"? What error are you getting, or what is happening?

Comment: A `require()` within an `include()`? Do you know the difference?

Comment: Sometimes error do not show up until network error. I believed that FirePHP scripts inside the PHP functions cause network error. I learnt more about relative links in HTML and PHP. I manage to make it work. Only remaining problem is FirePHP in PHP functions. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Bondye Oh ya... Never thought that I should use  require to  cause error in the event of missing or wring link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `/` first, you include file from root FS

Use

```
include_once './../toggleFirePHP.php';
```

and

```
include_once 'toggleFirePHP.php'; //ok
```

Comment: Now  I begin to understand the usage of relative links better. Relative links are different in HTML and PHP. Sigh... Also i noticed that $firephp scripts do not work well inside PHP functions. I am using FirePHP Core.

Answer (score 0):

See the [link](http://freepages.computers.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~pasher/links.htm) and [link](http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/)

- Correct one in securedlogin.php is '/toggleFirePHP.php'.
- Correct one in toggleFirePhp.php is 'firephp_include.php'.
- Correct one in main.php is 'toggleFirePHP.php' and
  '/secured/securedlogin.php'

The file system for root looks like below:-

```
Root folder
    toggleFirePHP.php
    main.php
    alertmessage.php
    firephp_include.php
    secured folder
         securedlogin.php
```