# How do I enqueue or activate a page of code in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, post, enqueue

I am developing a WordPress custom-theme where I would like to register my Custom Post Type and Taxonomy upon theme install, I have all the generated cpt-code inside my ***~custom-theme/custom/posttypes.php*** and ***taxonomy.php*** See it here on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jzEWBBvh).

I am very new a PHP but know that I must put some `add_action` or *enqueue* function inside my `functions.php` file so this post type will get registered on theme activation.

The function name in this example for the PostType is `function cptui_register_my_cpts_testimonials()` and for the Taxonomy is `function cptui_register_my_taxes_client-types()`

The reason I don't want all this code inside `function.php` is it will get too long, so hoping for a way to just fire this with a line or two of code from my `functions.php` file.

Comment: What is your question? How to split a large PHP file?

Comment: for some reason I was think my function would not fire if its in `~custom-theme/custom/posttypes.php` and not somehow linked to the functions.php page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks merely as a question how you would like to organize the code across files to me.

In PHP this can be done by *requiring* files. For example in `functions.php` as it is always loaded by Wordpress with the theme, you can *require* the custom post-types and taxonomy (just showing the beginning of the file exemplary):

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

/*
 * my theme - functions.php
 */

require_once __DIR__ . '/custom/posttypes.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/custom/taxonomy.php';

...
```

Commonly such *requires* (sometimes called *require lines*) are towards the very top of the file so that it is clear on which other files it depends (and what is available to write code with) immediately.

---

**References:**

- [`require_once`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)
- [`__DIR__` Magic Constant<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php)
- [`functions.php`<sup>*WP-Theme*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/)
- [How to call function of one php file from another php file and pass parameters to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8104998/367456)
- [What do strict types do in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48723637/367456)

---

Comment: Perfect, That is exactly what I was looking for!! Although for some reason the `declare(strict_types=1);` just ran into an error: `~Fatal error: strict_types declaration must be the very first statement ....` was I supposed to put that in someplace else?

Comment: @ShrockCo: It must be at the beginning of the file, see as well https://stackoverflow.com/q/48723637/367456 which I added.

Comment: Okay so you mean that would go at the top of my `~custom-theme/custom/posttypes.php` and `taxonomy.php` files? From php manual it would look like I need to wrap my code inside the curly brackets then?
`<?php
declare(ticks=1); {
function cptui_register_my_cpts_testimonials()
// and the rest of the entire script here }
?>`

Comment: no idea where you found an example for [`declare()`](https://php.net/declare) with curly brackets ... they are not required and I wonder why someone put them there (they probably don't hurt, but look entirely superfluous).

Comment: I got it from [php.net/declare](https://www.php.net/declare) but good to know that the brackets aren't required then.

Comment: Ah now I see it in there. Don't use the curly brackets (`{`, `}`) with `declare(strict_types=1);`. This was specifically mentioned in the documentation for `declare(ticks=1)` and does _**not**_ apply with `declare(strict_types=1)`. See also the code in my answer above, it does not have it and `<?php` should symbolize the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thank-you again for your enlightenment! Would you mind sharing what exactly `declare(strict_types=1);` really does?

Comment: @ShrockCo: No idea what your background is. The _short_ version is that it _enables strict type checking for scalar types in PHP_ (since PHP 7.0, see [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.strict)). Let me know if this is already useful and perhaps if on Stackoverflow the info appears lost or if on PHP.net it can be improved. Strict comparisons on scalar types are normally pretty useful to divide between request processing code (the basic input) and your own handling code (e.g. in a functions.php in Wordpress). It works per file.