# What's happens if someone tries to load my authentication file?

Tags: php

> If a persistent and malicious user got lucky and loaded one of your
>   secret files into the browser, and that secret files contains a lot of
>   variables that are only defined if the file was redirected, what do you do?

This a verifying script for login.php, which was my ***original*** script

```
if (!isset($_POST['email']) && !isset($_POST['pwd'])) {
    header ('Location: http://localhost/grace/verify/login.php');
    exit;
}
// connect to database
$verify = 'SELECT pwd FROM users WHERE email = ?';
// query

if ($password == $storedPwd) {
    $_SESSION['verified'] = 'yay!';
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    session_regenerate_id();
    header ("Location: $redirect");
    exit;
} else {
    $error = 'Invalid Email or password';
}
```

> There might be so many other ways to do the same script, but in my scenario, to solve my problem, the solution is my answer in the answers below.

Comment: You should post it in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Well, the simple "best" way would be to have the files stored inside the project, but outside of the webserver document root.

Comment: What secret file? They won't see the PHP code if you've got stuff set up right.

Comment: It sounds like you're confused [about a fundamental concept of PHP scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299571/can-php-files-be-viewed-across-the-internet-like-html-files).

Comment: @JonStirling so like under public_html, but under a different folder?

Comment: @Gnahzllib public_html is often the web root, so no, outside of that.

Comment: @JonStirling thank you :) ~~

Answer (score -1):

Ok, a lot of people who read this post did not even bother to read my script, I'm going to clarify my question and answer my own question.

If a user, let's say, she got lucky, and load one of your secret files like `authenticate.php`, in which there are variables are only defined if she is redirected from another page like `login.php`. So my solution is to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    header('Location: http://localhost/grace/login.php');
} else {
    $path = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    if (!$path == '/login.php') {
        header('Location: http://localhost/grace/login.php');
    } else {
        // run the code
    }
}
```

This will make sure that no one can directly load your secret files into the browser.

Comment: No idea of what you mean with "secret" (my concept of secret is e.g. a TXT file with a password). If you mean PHP source code, the attacker cannot see the source code unless you have blatant configuration errors. If you mean "secret URL only validated users know" you should password protect the location, not rely on people not knowing its URL. And whatever you try to accomplish with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`: a malicious user can easily forge it, an honest user can have it removed by an over-zealous proxy or firewall.

Comment: This is not a good solution. `HTTP_REFERER` is something that can be easily modified by an attacker (and it's not even guaranteed to be sent at all - some privacy extensions and proxies block it). The real solution is to use PHP's sessions on the "secret" page - check `$_SESSION['verified']` and throw an error or redirect to the login page on the secret pages if it's not set.

Comment: Incidentally, we did read your question. It just was very poorly explained.

Comment: Please see the link above in my comment on your question.  The PHP file's contents won't ever be displayed to the user, unless there is a terrible terrible configuration issue.  The likelihood of the PHP file contents being displayed to the user under normal circumstances is virtually zero.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález WOW... where did you learn all these? these are the stuff I try to learn but could not find a place to learn!

Comment: I guess that if you enjoy learning you just pick stuff here and there along the years. The key point is to learn little by little but make sure you actually understand what you use so far.